# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException:PDO There is no active transaction in /home/qndt0n0hz1u8/public_html/register.php:185 Stack trace

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am new to server mysql database, i just hosted my server with godaddy, connected to the database, my select query is working fine. After several trouble shooting i decided to use pdo transactions but am getting this error

My php registration script for insertion into database which is not working is show below:

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','1');
require_once('dbh.php');
require_once'config.php';


    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' &&  isset($_POST['f_name']) && isset($_POST['u_name']) && ($_POST['f_name']) !="" && ($_POST['u_name']) !="" && ($_POST['Email']) !="" && ($_POST['phonenumber']) !="" ) {
        /* id should be an auto-increment field in the db */

        $f_name = isset($_POST['f_name']) ? $_POST['f_name'] : false;
        $u_name = isset($_POST['u_name']) ? $_POST['u_name'] : false;
        $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : false;
        $password1 = isset($_POST['password1']) ? $_POST['password1'] : false;
        $Email = isset($_POST['Email']) ? $_POST['Email'] : false;
        $phonenumber = isset($_POST['phonenumber']) ? $_POST['phonenumber'] : false;
        $sponsor = isset($_GET['sponsor']) ? $_GET['sponsor'] : false;
        echo $sponsor;


        $error_fname = "";
        $eror_fname = "";
        $errror_fname = "";
        $eror_uname = "";
        $errror_uname = "";
        $error_uname = "";
        $eror_password = "";
        $errror_password = "";
        $error_password = "";
        $eror_email = "";
        $error_email = "";
        $errror_email = "";
        $eror_phonenumber = "";
        $error_phonenumber = "";
        $errror_phonenumber = "";
        $error_captcha = "";

        $error_sponsor = "";
        $errorSmt = "";


         if(isset($_POST['f_name'])  && isset($_POST['u_name']) && isset(($_POST['Email'])) && isset($_POST['phonenumber']) ) {




                    $errror_fname = $f_name.' is OK';


            //check for duplicate username
            $con= new PDO("mysql:host=$serverhost;dbname=silverhub;" , $serverusername, $serverpassword);
            $query = $con->prepare("SELECT userid FROM users WHERE u_name=? LIMIT 1");
            $u_Check = $query->bindParam(1, $u_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $u_Check = $query->execute();
            $u_Check = $query->rowCount();
            if( $u_Check=$query->rowCount() > 0) {
                $eror_uname = ' Sorry'.$u_name.' already taken, please choose another';

                }else{
                    $errror_uname = $u_name.' is OK';

                }

            //check for duplicate referral
            $query = $con->prepare("SELECT sponsor FROM users WHERE userid=? LIMIT 1");
            $s_Check = $query->bindParam(1, $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $s_Check = $query->execute();
            $s_Check= $query ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if( $s_Check['sponsor'] == $u_name) {
               $error_sponsor =  'Sorry, user cannot refer himself';

            }
            //check referral Email
            $query = $con->prepare("SELECT userid FROM users WHERE Email=? LIMIT 1");
            $e_Check = $query->bindParam(1, $Email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $e_Check = $query->execute();
            $e_Check = $query->rowCount();
            if( $p_Check=$query->rowCount() > 0) {
                $eror_email =  $Email.' already taken, please choose another';

            }else{
                $errror_email = $Email. ' is OK';

            }
            //check for duplicate phonenumber
            $query = $con->prepare("SELECT userid FROM users WHERE phonenumber=? LIMIT 1");
            $p_Check = $query->bindParam(1, $phonenumber, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $p_Check = $query->execute();
            $p_Check = $query->rowCount();
            if( $al_Check=$query->rowCount() > 0) {
               $eror_phonenumber =  $phonenumber.' already taken, please choose another';

            }else{
                $errror_phonenumber = $phonenumber. ' is OK';

            }                  
        }

        // if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/",$f_name) && strip_tags(trim($f_name))) {
        //     $error_fname = 'invalid, fullname must be alphanumerics with no whitespace';
        //     echo 'invalid, fullname must be alphanumerics with no whitespace';

        // }
        if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/",$u_name) && strip_tags(trim($u_name))) {
            $error_uname = 'invalid, username must be alphanumerics with no whitespace';


        }

        if(strlen($u_name) < 3 || strlen($u_name) > 16) {
         $error_uname = 'Username must be between 3 - 16 characters';

        }
        if($password !== $password1) {
           $error_password = 'Password and RepeatPassword do not match';

        }
        if(strlen($password) < 5) {
           $error_password = 'Weak password, Password must be more than 5 characters';

        }
        if(strlen($phonenumber) > 11  && trim(htmlentities($phonenumber))) {
            $error_phonenumber = 'Phonenumbers must be an 11 digit number';

        }

        if(!filter_var($Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $error_email = ' invalid email address, please verify your email address';

        }

        if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/",$sponsor) && strip_tags(trim($sponsor))) {
            $error_sponsor = 'invalid sponsor name, must be alphanumeric ';

        }
        if(empty($_POST['recaptcha'])) {

            $error_captcha = 'Enter the Verification Code Above';

        }
        elseif($_POST['recaptcha'] != $_SESSION['recaptcha']) {

            $error_captcha = 'Verification Code did not match, try again';

        }elseif($_POST['recaptcha'] == $_SESSION['recaptcha']) {

            $error_captcha = 'Verification Matched, Click Register';

        }

        if($u_name && $eror_fname =="" && $error_fname =="" && $errror_fname !=="" && $eror_uname =="" && $error_uname =="" && $errror_uname !==""  && $error_password =="" && $eror_email == "" && $error_email == "" && $errror_email !== "" && $eror_phonenumber =="" && $error_phonenumber =="" && $errror_phonenumber !=="" ) {

        class reg extends dbh {

         public function userCheck($f_name, $u_name,$password,$Email,$phonenumber,$sponsor) {
        try {

            $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->serverhost;dbname=silverhub;", $this->serverusername, $this->serverpassword);
            $con->beginTransaction();
            $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


                $passenc = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, array('cost'=>11));
                $emailCode = rand().$phonenumber;
                $smsCode = rand().$u_name;
                $Active = 0;
                $Has_reserved_person = 'NO';
                $MainTime = time(); 
                $con= new PDO("mysql:host=$this->serverhost;dbname=silverhub;", $this->serverusername, $this->serverpassword);
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users (f_name,u_name,password,Email,emailCode,phonenumber,smsCode,sponsor,Active,Has_reserved_person,MainTime) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                $insert = $con->prepare($sql);
                $insert->bindParam(1,$f_name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $insert->bindParam(2,$u_name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $insert->bindParam(3,$passenc );
                $insert->bindParam(4,$Email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $insert->bindParam(5,$emailCode,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $insert->bindParam(6,$phonenumber,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $insert->bindParam(7,$smsCode,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $insert->bindParam(8,$sponsor,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $insert->bindParam(9,$Active);
                $insert->bindParam(10,$Has_reserved_person);
                $insert->bindParam(11,$MainTime);
                $insert->execute();
                $con->commit();



                    if($insert->execute()){
                    echo 'insert successfull';
                     }else{
                echo  "Execute query error, because:" . print_r($con->errorinfo());
                return false;
           }



    } catch (PDOException $e){

        throw $e;
    }
}


        }
        $object = new reg();
        $object->userCheck( $f_name, $u_name, $password, $Email, $phonenumber, $sponsor);

        }
    }
?>
```

Here is my HTML FORM input:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html !doctype>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="sec">REGISTER WITH US</div>
        <img src="images/images(33).jpg">

        <form action='register.php' method='POST' class='ajax-reg'>

   <!-- HOW does a user enter a value here if it is HIDDEN??? Removed `required` attribute -->

   <div class='form-group'>
       <p> Note!!! Fields with astericks must be filled</p>
      <input type='hidden' class='form-control' name='userid' placeholder='enter your id' />
   </div>
   <br>

   <div class='form-group'>
      <label>fullname*</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" onblur ="fnamecheck()" id="f_name"  name="f_name" placeholder="Enter your fullname" value="<?php echo @$_POST['f_name']?>"  /><span id ="fullnameStatus"></span>
   </div>

    <br>
   <div class='form-group'>
      <label>username*</label>
      <input type="username" class="form-control" name="u_name" id ="u_name" onblur ="usernamecheck()" placeholder="Enter your username" value="<?php echo @$_POST['u_name']?>"  /><span id ="usernameStatus"></span>
   </div>


   <br>
   <div class='form-group' >
      <label>password*</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" onblur ="passcheck()" placeholder="type in your password"   />
   </div>


   <br>

   <div class='form-group' >
      <label>RepeatPassword*</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password1" id ="password1" onblur ="passcheck()" placeholder= "Retype in your password"  /><span id ="passwordStatus"></span>
   </div>

   <br>
   <div class='form-group'>
      <label>email*</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="Email" id ="Email" onblur ="emailcheck()" placeholder="Enter your email" value="<?php echo @$_POST['Email']?>"  /><span id ="emailStatus"></span>
   </div>


   <br>

   <div class='form-group'>
      <label>phonenumber*</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="phonenumber" id = "phonenumber" onblur ="phcheck()" placeholder="Enter your phonenumber" value="<?php echo @$_POST['phonenumber']?>"  /><span id ="phonenumberStatus"></span>
   </div>

   <br>
   <div>
        <?php if (isset($_GET['sponsor']) && $_GET['sponsor'] != "") {?>

        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="sponsor" id ="sponsor" onblur ="usernamecheck()" placeholder="type in your sponsor username here" value="<?php $sponsor = $_GET['sponsor'];?>" />
        <?php  }?>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="captcha"><img src="captcha.php"></div>
  <br>
  <div id="refresh"><p>    Refresh To Change Code</p></div>
    <div id="captcha">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="recaptcha" id = "recaptcha" onblur ="recaptchacheck()" placeholder="Enter The Code Above"  /><span><?php echo @$error_captcha?></span><span id ="recaptchaStatus"></span>
    </div>

   <div class='form-group'>
      <!-- this checkbox needs a name!! Assign name `terms` -->
      <input type="checkbox" name="terms" required />
   </div>
   <div id="terms">  </a><a href="terms.php" >I agree with terms and conditions</a></div>
   <div>
       <input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' name='submit_signup' value='REGISTER' />
   </div>
   <br>
</form>
<br>
<div></div>
    </div>
   <footer>

   </footer>
    <script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jqueryfunctions.js"></script>
    <script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="ajaxfiles.js">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but the insert query is working perfectly in my local host, please any errors? am confused!! OR is godaddy server insert query different?

Comment: And *how* do you know it's failing? If you don't get an error, then we cartainly can't come up with one. And that's way too much code to sift through. (The form part seems unneeded). Make an [mcve]. Use the [edit] button.

Comment: @mario i have provided error it echoed, please can you look into the script and help me once more

Comment: I think this line `$stmt= $con->prepare("INSERT INTO referral (userid,u_name,sponsor) VALUES ('".$lastid."','".$u_name."','".$sponsor."')");` should be `$stmt= $con->exec("INSERT INTO referral (userid,u_name,sponsor) VALUES ('".$lastid."','".$u_name."','".$sponsor."')");
` since you are not actually preparing it using ? and bindParam.

Comment: That's not the actual error. Maybe you should get rid of your try/catch and substitute the misleading `$con->errorinfo()`?

Comment: i have removed the referral insert query, help look at the main insert query to see if their are errors, please

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: You're using prepared statements in most cases, but there's one that's not and it's a huge problem. [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) are a big deal and you really don't want to have them in your code. **Always** use prepared statements with placeholder values unless you have no other option.

Comment: please @tadman, show me how to use prepared statements with place values

Comment: Your code has several such examples. Do you want me to explain your own code back to you? If you're not sure how all this code works, that's fine, we all have to learn, but it also means you're probably going to break a lot of things before you get it working.

Comment: If you're just getting started I'd strongly suggest using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/). This will give you patterns to follow for organizing your code into proper model, view and controller contexts. What you have here is a confused stew of concerns, with HTML, PHP, SQL, and JavaScript all jumbled together. Frameworks come in many forms from really lean like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to exceptionally full-featured like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) and many spots in between.

Comment: @tadman thanks for your concern, all i need now is correction of my errors not blames, we all learn gradually

Comment: Thanks friends for all your responses, i have resolved the problem, the error was from phpmyadmin, i didn't set any default null value for some of the columns